# vlookup problems with copy/paste

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a spreadsheed where I have used the vlookup function.  As far as I know, that part is working correctly. However, I want to copy and paste the results of the formula and not the formula itself.  Normally I would just paste special- values (and indeed, that's what a google search tells me to do).  However, when I try to do that, the only cell that is pasted is the first cell.  how can I fix this?

Because I am only using the formula in cells that are blank, would that be a reason that copy/paste isn't working correctly?

Here is the VLOOKUP code that I am using: `=VLOOKUP(BE53, $BA$2:$BB$9999, 2, FALSE)` and then I drag is down to copy it.

Comment: A picture might be helpful here and elaborate on the "using the formula in cells that are blank".  There is nothing special about `VLOOKUP` or any formula in this case.  Copying and pasting values should have no surprises.  Select the whole range, copy, and paste values where you want them.

Comment: I can't post a picture because the sheet I'm using has confidential information.  But the sheet is like this:

First column: Numerical Codes
Second Column: Abbreviations
Third column: numerical codes
fourth column: abbreviations

The two sets of columns (1,2 and 3,4) the correspondence between numbers and abbrevations is identical.  However, column four has many missing abbreviations.  What I'm doing is filtering so only blank column four is visible, then using VLOOKUP to get the correct abbreviation.  The problem is when I copy/paste special: values, the abbreviations are different.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with a couple of non-confidential examples?  If not can you provide the `VLOOKUP` formula that you are using?  Beware that copying from data that has hidden rows will only copy the visible data.  When you paste, you will end up with a result that is shorter than the whole data set.  Is your problem possibly related to this feature/issue?  Also, please [edit these details back into your original question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30739792/edit) so others can follow more easily.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
In the SOURCE sheet, 
copy the range that contains vlookup formula
paste special (value) to the same SOURCE sheet (but in different range)

and then 
copy the pasted values to the DESTINATION sheet (normal copy-paste not paste-special)

a little bit work-around but perhaps it can work

Answer (score 1):

Use the "copy" function as usual, but use "paste special" (CTRL + Alt + V) and choose values only when you paste it.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Paste-values-not-formulas-12687B4D-C79F-4137-B0CC-947C229C55B9

Answer (score 0):

Rather than copy paste, could you just point the cell/database/ppt/whatever at the cells in question?

For example, if vlookup is in Sheet1 A1 and you are copying it to Sheet2 A1, just type "=sheet1A1" into sheet2 A1?

It gets more complicated if you want to put it somewhere else but the principle holds.

Answer (score -1):

Select everything that you need to copy, then just CTRL + C, go to the first cell where u need to paste it and press CTRL + ALT + V and select values then Enter

Comment: I've tried this, and the only thing that copies is the very first cell.